# Convert JSON form and render to HTML

Tags: html, json, forms, post, render

I am working on a form builder that saves and displays, currently im stuck. Im completely new to the concept of JSON but im looking to render the below code to an html form( just an example)

```
[{"type":"text","label":"Test","req":1},{"type":"textarea","label":"123456789","req":0},{"type":"select","label":"example","req":0,"choices":[{"label":"1","sel":0},{"label":"2","sel":0},{"label":"3","sel":0}]}]
```

Any help would be apreciated.
Most examples I see online are for the post submission json data and not displaying the actual form

Comment: you need to use javascript code to foreach all data that you have in loop and generate html code to variable, base on that you have in your json.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write code to parse the json object, something like this:

```
function buttonclick() {
  var jsonvalue = [{"type":"text","label":"Test","req":1},{"type":"textarea","label":"123456789","req":0}];
  var htmlstring ="";

  for(var i=0; i<jsonvalue.length; i++)
  {
      htmlstring+= "<input type=\"" + jsonvalue[i].type + "\" name=\"" + jsonvalue[i].label + "\" />";
  }
  alert (htmlstring);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the `required` attribute on required fields.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you. I created a function that loops over your array of objects. I runs the field type through a switch statement and when it finds that type it creates that input type.

I also created a function for the select options to decouple the forEach loops. It make it easier to read and maintain.

```
    var formData = [{"type":"text","label":"Test","req":1},{"type":"textarea","label":"123456789","req":0},{"type":"select","label":"example","req":0,"choices":[{"label":"1","sel":0},{"label":"2","sel":0},{"label":"3","sel":0}]}];


    createForm(formData);

    function createForm(arr){
        var $formTmp = $('<form></form>');

        arr.forEach( function(obj, idx) {
            var $fieldSet,
                $selctOpts = $('<select name=""></select>'),
                inputType = obj.type; 

            switch (inputType){
                case 'text':
                    $fieldSet = $('<label for="">'+obj.label+'</label>');

                    if ( obj.req === 1) {
                        $fieldSet.append('<input type="text" required>');
                    } else {
                        $fieldSet.append('<input type="text">');
                    }
                    $formTmp.append($fieldSet, '<br />');
                    break;
                case 'textarea':
                    $fieldSet = $('<label for="">'+obj.label+'</label><br /><textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>');
                    $formTmp.append($fieldSet, '<br />');
                    break;
                case 'select':
                    $fieldSet = $('<label for=""></label>').text(obj.label);
                    addOptions($selctOpts, obj.choices);                    
                    $formTmp.append($fieldSet, $selctOpts, '<br />');
                    break;
                default:
                    alert('There was no input type found.');
                    break;
            }               
        });

        // render to body.
        $('body').append($formTmp);


        // Loop for the select options.
        function addOptions(elem, arr){
            arr.forEach(function(obj){
                elem.append('<option value="'+obj.sec+'">'+obj.label+'</option>');              
            });
        }
    }
```